# “Era”, “age”, and “epoch”

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

What are the differences and relations between *era*, *age*, and *epoch*? For example, should I say one of these?

- We are now in the digital *era*.
- We are now in the digital *age*.
- We are now in the digital *epoch*.
- We are now in the Internet *era*.
- We are now in the Internet *age*.
- We are now in the Internet *epoch*.

Or should I use some other word?

I found this [comparison](http://www.knewance.com/comparisons/eon-v-era-v-period-v-epoch-v-age.html), but it is all about geologic history.

Comment: Question is incomplete: should show evidence of research effort.

Comment: ... and what does the dictionary tell you?

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA604#v=onepage&q=era&f=false

Comment: *"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair ..."* — Dickens

Comment: @PeterShor:Thanks! What does Dickens teach us on my question? which one would you use with technical words, such as digital and internet?

Comment: Dickens is using *age, epoch, season* as synonyms here. I'd add *era* to that list, as well. (And I consider *seasons* to be shorter than the others.)

Comment: @PeterShor: Which one do you think is more formal (either verbal or textual communication), and which is more used in informal verbal communication?

Comment: @tim - it teaches us that Dickens was a journalist paid by the word

Comment: @mgb:What do you mean by "paid by the word"? Like paid by playing meaningless and superficial word games?

Comment: @Tim: "paid by the word" means "paid in direct proportion to the number of words written".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In geological time, these terms have specific meanings, but otherwise, according to the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epoch), they have similar meanings.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geologic_time_scale#Terminology):

```
Eras are divided into periods, epochs and ages.
Era: several hundred million years
Epoch: tens of millions of years
Age: millions of years
```

For your question however, anything digital or Internet related is not going to qualify for any of these words using geological definitions, and the exact definitions of these words are much more relaxed.

"Era" is used colloquially to refer to any period of time with a name. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era#Colloquial_.22eras.22).

It seems to be more common to call it the "Information Age", as evidenced by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Age) and Google search results:

```
Number of search results from Google:
digital age - 986 million
digital era - 309 million
digital epoch - 8 million
Internet age - 1010 million
Internet era - 126 million
Internet epoch - 7 million
information age - 1450 million
```

Answer (score 4):

In non-geological contexts, the terms "age" and "era" are more commonly used than "epoch" in the kinds of usage you cite. I would say "age" and "era" are roughly synonymous and would imply time scales of from a few decades to a few centuries.  However "epoch" does bring in more connotations of geological time, so it would imply much larger time scales of at least a few centuries.

Answer (score 1):

Epoch is from latin and age is from french, you may also use 'time'.

There are numerous foreign words were imported from ancient time; in daily usage there is no difference.

Comment: Actually, according to etymonline, [epoch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=epoch) is from Greek, and [age](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=age) from Latin. I fail to see how this provides an answer to the question, though, even if the etymologies would have been correctly attributed.